# Bootstrap modal doesn't work correctly with bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm developping a Bootstrap application inside the intranet of a company. The intranet is composed of a navbar made with Bootstrap and my application is included under this navbar. In the intranet both css and js bootstrap files are included and my app is included with the PHP command "include_once".

I have made a simple button which trigger a modal dialog. It works perfectly but the events on open or close the modal don't work.
When I include *bootstrap.js* in my application the events work : I created an event which show an alert when the modal is closed :

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      alert("closed");
    })
</script>
```

When I use the close button or the close icon, the alert is displayed, but when I click outside of the modal, the modal is closed but I don't have the alert because I find out that this line was created twice :

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

It seems that the *bootstrap.js* file, included in the general page is only half used and if I include mine, some things are done twice.

Do you have a solution for that problem ?

Comment: are you saying that modal opens even if you do not include bootstrap.js?

Comment: Yes and it works perfectly ! But I have to use bootstrap.js to use events

Comment: that means that bootstrap.js(or just modal.js) is already included maybe?

Comment: You're right ! It's already included but the event on open/close of the modal don't work !